# Word problem regarding system of linear congruences...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Full problem:

> A hoard of gold pieces ‘comes into the possession of’ a band of $15$ pirates.
>   When they come to divide up the coins, they find that three are left over.
>   Their discussion of what to do with these extra coins becomes animated,
>   and by the time some semblance of order returns there remain only $7$
>   pirates capable of making an effective claim on the hoard. When, however,
>   the hoard is divided between these seven it is found that two pieces are left
>   over. There ensues an unfortunate repetition of the earlier disagreement,
>   but this does at least have the consequence that the four pirates who remain
>   are able to divide up the hoard evenly between them. What is the minimum
>   number of gold pieces which could have been in the hoard?

So the information that I picked out from this was, using equivalence classes
$$[x]_{15}=[3]_{15}$$
$$[x]_7=[2]_7$$
$$[x]_4=[0]_4$$

I solved the system and obtained $[-390]_{420}=[30]_{420}$. The answer to our problem is supposedly $408$, but from the point that I've gotten to, I am not quite sure how to get this number. Did I overlook something big? Or am I on the right track?

**EDIT:**

I re-calculated and obtained $[12]_{420}$. Or $x \equiv 12 \mod 420$. If only it were $-12$...

**EDIT 2:**

Nevermind. I've got the answer. I had a sign error and indeed my answer is $[-12]_{420}$.

Comment: Since $30$ is neither congruent to $3$ mod $15$ nor to $0$ mod $4$, you must have done something wrong when solving the system.

Comment: I would prefer not to use equivalence classes. We have that the number $x$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$. Your answer is not congruent to $0$ modulo $4$, so something went wrong with the Chinese Remainder Theorem calculation.

Comment: Re Edit 2: Now simply add $420$ to $-12$ to get $[408]_{420}$. Recall, we want the minimum number of gold pieces. That number should be $\geq 0$. Does it make sense to say $-12$ gold pieces?

Comment: Nope itt doesn't make sense as I have it as in Edit 2. Sooooo...

We have x = -12 + 420q for some q. So if we let $x_{min}$ denote our minimum number of gold pieces and letting q=1, we obtain $x_{min}=-12+420 \implies x_{min}=408$

Answer (score 1):

Have 
$$x \equiv 3 \mod 15$$
$$x \equiv 2 \mod 7$$
$$x \equiv 0 \mod 4$$
Using Chinese Remainder Theorem, we first solve
$$x \equiv 3 \mod 15$$
$$x \equiv 2 \mod 7$$
Since $15,7$ are relatively prime, we have
$$15(1)+7(-2)=1$$
$$\implies 15(1)(2)+7(-2)(3)=30-42=-12$$
$$\implies x \equiv 93 \mod 105$$

Now we need to solve the system 
$$x \equiv 93 \mod 105$$
$$x \equiv 0 \mod 4$$
Since $105,4$ are relatively prime, we have
$$105(1)+4(-26)=1$$
$$\implies 105(1)(0)+4(-26)(93)=(-104)(93)=-9672$$
$$\implies x \equiv -9672 \mod 420$$

Note that $420\cdot 23=9660$, so $-9672+9660=-12$. Further, observe that $420-12=408$. Thus,
$$x \equiv 408 \mod 420$$

So the minimum number of gold pieces is 408.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\   
&& {\rm mod}\ 15\!:\,\ {-x}\equiv \color{#c00}{12}\\
&& {\rm mod}\ \ \ 7\!:\,\ {-x}\equiv  5\equiv \color{#c00}{12}\\
&& {\rm mod}\ \ \ 4\!:\,\ {-x}\equiv  0\equiv\color{#c00}{12}\end{eqnarray}\ \iff\ {-}x\equiv{\color{#c00}{12}}
\,\ ({\rm mod\ 15\cdot 7\cdot 4)}$

**Remark** $\ $ The above is a special case of the following *constant case* CRT optimization

$\begin{eqnarray}\phantom{\bf Hint}\   
&& {\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ {y}\equiv \color{#c00}{a}\\
&& {\rm mod}\ \  n\!:\,\ {y}\equiv  b\equiv \color{#c00}{a}\\
&& {\rm mod}\ \ \, k\!:\,\ {y}\equiv  c\equiv \color{#c00}{a}\end{eqnarray}\ \iff\ y\equiv{\color{#c00}{a}}
\,\ ({\rm mod\ lcm}(m,n,k))$